# php post method not functional

Tags: php, post

Can someone assist me with figuring out why my form isn't doing anything/not functioning.  I am very new to programming so bear with me if you can.  When the submit button is pressed nothing at happens.  I want it to recall something based off of what is entered in the text field. (nothing in particular, just trying to experiement/learn.)

This is in my html file:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fname" valude="pdate"/>
```

this is in my process.php file:

```
$fdate = $_POST['fname'];

setcookie ("user", $fdate, time() +60*60*24*365);

if (isset($_COOKIE['user'])){
        var_dump ($_COOKIE);
}
else{
        header('fname:index.html');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What part is not working, in particular? That is, what are you expecting it to do, and what is actually happening? (also, I think you mean "value" not "valude" up in that first code block...)

Answer (score 2):

The PHP superglobals (_COOKIE, _FILES, _POST, _GET, _REQUEST) are set when the script is first started up, and then PHP never touches them again.

When you do your set cookie, that cookie will NOT magically appear in the $_COOKIE superglobal until the NEXT page request. It has to be round-tripped to the client first.

Answer (score 0):

This code Worked For Me :

Test.php

```
< ?php
if( isset( $_POST['fname'] ) )
{
    setcookie ("user", $_POST['fname'], time() +60*60*24*365);
}

if( isset( $_COOKIE['user'] ) )
{
    echo 'COOKIE IS SET';
} else
{
    echo 'COOKIE NOT SET';
}
?> 
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="pdate" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: is that within the html file or the php file?

Comment: Test On PHP File, But not different, i give you this code to solved your problem on your codes, because i haven't your full code

Comment: Edited, replace < ?PHP to <?PHP

Comment: And you got COOKIE IS SET, in the first request?